# Is it possible to change variable inside @EJB while testing

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, jndi, schedule

Assume I have EJB that make some action every hour. I'm using jboss ejb @Schedule  for it. Also this schedule need to work only on production, so I add a flag for it.

```
@Stateless
public class Remover {    
  private boolean testMode = false;

  @Schedule(hour = "*/1", persistent = false)
  protected void init() {    
    if (testMode) return;
    doSomeCode();
  }
}
```

And now in my tests I create embeded EJB container and want to directly call doSomeCode(), but init() is also running sometimes ruining my test.

```
Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<>();
props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.openejb.client.LocalInitialContextFactory");
EJBContainer cnt = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(props);
Context ctx = cnt.getContext();

Remover r = (Remover) ctx.lookup("java:global/RemoveService/Remover");
r.doSomeCode();
```

So, the question is, can I change testMode variable while creating EJBContainer. I found that it can be changed by adding new props to EJBContainer, and added @Resource annotation to variable, but no luck, maybe there is need another jndi name.

```
props.put("java:comp/env/testMode", "true");
```

Also if there is way to disable @Schedule while testing it will also helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your server to use expression resolution thus allowing you to change the value. http://wildscribe.github.io/WildFly/14.0/subsystem/ee/#attr-annotation-property-replacement

Answer (score 0):

This is an example for a deployment descriptor, you can add the variable and the schedule expression to your deplyment descriptor either in production or in development environment and set the default for the other one, or do everything in the descriptor